# Is it true that the cupid bow is "lucky"

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I've heard from many people that the cupid bow is supposed to be "lucky", they say that if the monster, or god could drop a potion it would or if it could drop an un-tired item it would.

Is this possible?

Comment: what game is this for

Comment: realm of the mad god

Comment: That would be completely unbalanced, and last time I played (quite some time ago) balance was something rather important in the game.

Comment: it could just have an addition to the chance percentage, that would seem legit

Answer (score 3):

No, it's all about the RNG. There are no items in the game that boost drop rates besides loot drop potions.